# Mongoose Schema.post across network

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two Node.js applications each running Mongoose on a different machine.  There is a single MongoDB database running on the first, and the second connects to it and adds documents periodically.  I'm trying to add a hook to the creation of these documents so the server running the database is aware that other server has added data.  I tried using the `Schema.post()` method, but it doesn't seem to work since there are two separate instances of Mongoose.  Is this true or am I just implementing it incorrectly?  I can get the hook to fire if the document is created on the same server, but not the other.

So my thought is to add the hook to MongoDB directly, instead of Mongoose, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is true, `Schema.post()` only work in the same process. You either need to use a library that tails MongoDB's `oplog` (like [mongo-oplog](https://github.com/cayasso/mongo-oplog)), implement it yourself using a message queue (or pub/sub) that all instances are connected to (like Redis, RabbitMQ, etc) or use a database that supports this natively. PostgreSQL supports this with its [`NOTIFY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-notify.html) feature for example.